# Amazon S3 + Cloudfront with Wordpress

Tags: cdn

I put together a wordpress site on a heroku free instance and I'm making all images to go to an S3 bucket and a Cloudfront distribution with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) . The thing is, it only uploads the images to S3 and serves them with the proper CNAME I set up.

What I want is to serve the wp-content (all my plugins and themes) through S3. I know it's possible because I've read about it, but all tutorials around are explaining the Origin pull and not this configuration. Can anyone tell me more about how can I achieve this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no remotely easy way to accomplish this with "push" strategy, because (unlike attachments) plugins and themes do not really declare their resources to WordPress.

To push those resources you need to enumerate them and keep that information up to date. In pull configurations this happens automagically in actual use. For push configuration you will either have to scan *everything* for assets and upload *all* of them, or build some kind of way (automated or manual) to figure out which are actually used.

In a nutshell - currently WP doesn't really manage of extension's assets and has little functionality to work with them. Thus prevalence of pull configurations you see reflected in information around.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst ! To configure 'pull' I only need to add my domain to cloudfront, right? Like, in exchange for the S3 bucket I'm poiting right now.

Comment: @AndréLucas and replace links in your site and stuff. See previously mentioned abundance of pull config tutorials. :)